# NullPointerException with getResource() while adding CSS to JavaFX application

Tags: java, css, javafx, nullpointerexception

A little confused with a NullPointerException that I am getting.  I am trying to add a .css file to my Main class.  Here is the code.

```
        //Load FXML file
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/HumansightFirstDraft.fxml"));

        // Create scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 600);

        //Load CSS
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/application/application.css").toExternalForm());

        // Display application
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();`
```

The application.css is in the same place as the Main.java.

Here is my console output.

```
Jan 10, 2019 8:30:20 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.191
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Here is my css.  I only have one change so as to make it easier to test.

```
#startSurvey {

-fx-border-radius: 30;

}
```

Here is my directory as seen in Eclipse.

[image: Screenshot of folder]

Comment: When the result of `getResource(...)` is `null` that means the resource couldn't be found at the specified location. Make sure you have the path correct and that the resource file is on the classpath.

Comment: I assumed that much, but the I've checked and rechecked the file path and it seems to be correct.  I will include a screenshot of my folder.

Comment: What happens if you use `getClass().getResource(...)` instead of `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)`?

Comment: The fact that the css file is included in the source folder does not automatically result in the IDE copying it to the build folders. Have you checked the folders containing the `.class` files for the css file?

Comment: So when I take out getClassLoader(), there is no error, but the css doesn't load.  I've had a weird thing since I started JavaFX where my programs only work when I include the getClassLoader().  Where would I find these folders?

Comment: You'll have to lookup where Eclipse (you appear to be using Eclipse) puts its build files (I'm not familiar with Eclipse). I'd find it strange that the CSS file would not be copied but the FXML would be, but IDEs can be strange sometimes. Check any settings that tell your IDE what files to include/exclude.

Comment: I was able to find it.  The unfortunate part is that it just proved to me that I do in fact have the right path.  I even cleaned and rebuilt the project.  I'm sure you can imagine I'm confused.  Are there any nuances with getResource?

Comment: When you say "_there is no error, but the css doesn't load_" what exactly happens? Do you get any warnings? Can you [edit] your question to include your CSS file?

Comment: I think it's time for a [mcve], including the fxml .. please mind the "minimal" :)

Comment: @Slaw What happens is that the window loads what I did in the scenebuilder, but doesn't load my css modifications.  In this case, all it was rounded corners on a button.  I will put it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont nee to say `/application/application.css`

Just write it like this `application.css`

**This is becsuse both the main class an the css file are in the same parent direvtory**

*The same as all the fxml files*

**Update**
It is also possible that the null pointer occurs in the controller of the fxml.

**Update 2**
Thanks to

> @kleopatra

dont use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` simply use `getClass().getResource()`

Comment: That's what I thought too.  But I tried that out and it didn't change.

Comment: beware, the getResource param interpretation is different for classloader vs class: classloader.getResource(absolutePath) - can have the leading slash or not, doesn't matter, vs. class.getResource(relativePath) without slash and absolute with slash. So something really fishy going on here ... most probably a head-on-table when found ;)

Comment: that's not what I meant (probably wasn't clear enough): we can use the one or other but must be aware of the difference :)

Comment: So, when I do what you said, I get no errors, but the nothing from the css is actually applied.

Comment: And you are sure of all the syntax of the css file.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  It is only one line, I edited it into the original post.

Comment: Your correction was right.  The problem ended up actually being in my CSS.  The -fx-border-radius characteristic does not change what I expected, so the css was applied, but in a visible way.  But thank you for teaching me about the difference between class... & class.classLoader()...